# I learned much of my English watching

Tags: grammaticality, prepositional-phrases, adverbials

1. I learned much of my English vocabulary watching Hollywood movies.
2. I learned much of my English vocabulary **from** watching Hollywood movies.
3. I learned much of my English vocabulary **by** watching Hollywood movies.

Are these correct and if so, do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Or ***through, when, while,...***

Comment: Why might you think this an example of ellipsis? Looking over these examples that analysis doesn't make sense to me given how [a far simpler explanation exists](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/594690/2085).

Comment: so all are correct?

Comment: Yes, they are all idiomatic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the correct explanations. They are **not** equivalent, contrary to some other 'answers'.

1. I learned much of my English vocabulary [while] watching Hollywood movies.

   - "watching Hollywood movies" modifies "I" and conveys the learning **circumstances**.
2. I learned much of my English vocabulary from watching Hollywood movies.

   - "watching Hollywood movies" is the **source** of the learning.
3. I learned much of my English vocabulary by watching Hollywood movies.

   - "watching Hollywood movies" is the **means** of the learning.

They are semantically different, even though similar in what they convey. They respectively answer:

1. **When** did you learn your English vocabulary?
2. **Where** did you learn your English vocabulary from?
3. **How** did you learn your English vocabulary?

Comment: Wow, easy with the scare quotes! And I would stand by my claim of equivalency, especially since I'd say the three suggested questions could each be answered reasonably by any of the three sentences.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I'm really not sure why you're analyzing the first sentence as a time thing. I wouldn't put "while" there; I might put "by" if anything. And it doesn't answer the question "When", because the answer should be a time, like say, "2011" or "when I was in high school" or "while working as a nurse". I think it doesn't work for "watching ..." because that's a recurring thing, not a specific time.

Comment: I think I found the mistake: "watching Hollywood movies" doesn't modify "I" (as in "while I was"), it modifies "learned", just like the others. Here's an example without a subject to demonstrate: "Learning English vocabulary watching Hollywood movies is what a lot of foreigners do." I think that's comparable to, say, "cutting down trees using a chainsaw". You wouldn't say "I cut down trees \*while using a chainsaw."

Comment: @wjandrea: I hope you don't mind me being frank. Many native speakers are not that familiar with the grammatical function participial phrases. While they seem to modify the verb phrase, they actually modify the noun phrase. There are many independent pieces of evidence for this: (1) The conjugation of the participle agrees with the declension of the noun phrase; in English this is limited to the number (singular/plural), but in other languages this includes case and gender. [cont]

Comment: [cont] (2) Negation clearly elucidates it; in "The people watching movies everyday learned a lot of English, but the people not watching movies everyday were healthier.", "not watching movies everyday" modifies "the people" (it is "the people who did not watch movies everyday" that were healthier). [cont]

Comment: [cont] (3) All the varied ways that English participial phrases are used are uniformly explained by what I said, and it is also the standard way of analyzing them in linguistics; see [this webpage](https://nmu.edu/writingcenter/participles) for examples of participial phrases, and note the examples "The teacher often saw Jerry throwing spitballs." and "The cook was seen by the man, making pizza.".

Comment: @wjandrea: Regarding "when", note that in English this word can be used more broadly than for just time. As you can see from [various lexicons](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/when), it can be used to refer to circumstances (e.g. "When did you ever see such a crowd?", "How will he get good grades when he didn't study?"), and in some cases (like the second example I just gave) it *cannot* be interpreted as referring to time.

Comment: @wjandrea: Regarding "while", being grammatically and semantically correct is a different and orthogonal issue from being idiomatic. It is not idiomatic to say "I cut down the trees while using a chainsaw", but it is *not incorrect*! It's simply because "while" is redundant and omitting it doesn't appear to cause euphony issues. Consider "It is hard to cut down trees while being blindfolded.", where dropping "while" is not so common because the "being" sounds odd (euphony issues).

Comment: Oops I accidentally made a mistake in (1); there is no number agreement in English either, unlike in many other languages. It only conveys aspect of the state ascribed to the noun phrase; the present participle (e.g. "watching") is for imperfect aspect, the perfect participle (e.g. "having watched") is for perfect aspect, and the passive participle (e.g. "watched") is for passive perfect aspect. English doesn't support some other conceptually viable combinations, whereas some other languages do.

Comment: @wjandrea: Furthermore, in "Learning English vocabulary watching Hollywood movies is what a lot of foreigners do", the reason there is no subject is simply because "learning" is an infinitive. This does not mean that participial phrases do not modify the (implicit) subject! Consider "Even if suffering, to hurt an innocent child intentionally is wrong.", where "suffering" modifies the implicit subject of "to hurt". A clearer example is "Even if working now, it will stop working eventually.", where obviously "working now" modifies "it" and definitely not "will stop working eventually"!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, these are all idiomatic and equivalent. But note, not all of these work in other contexts.

- I learned all my English **from** Fred. *—right*
- I learned all my English **by** Fred. *—wrong*
- I learned all my English Fred. *—wrong*

For these, we changed from a verb to a noun, so only "from" works.

Or:

- I made this bowl *by* carving it out of wood. *—right*
- I made this bowl *from* carving it out of wood. *—wrong*

Here we go back to a verb, but I changed the first phrase from "learn" to "make," and it means something different and so takes different helpers.

Comment: And yet *I learned much of my English vocabulary Monday afternoons at Fred’s woodworking class* needs no preposition.:)

Comment: How about "at"?

Comment: @tchrist - I bet you encountered plenty of _old saws_...

Answer (score -2):

None of those are really idiomatic, because "much" is used for non-countable nouns, and, unlike grammar, vocabulary is countable (words).

Idiomatic phrases would be:

- I learned most of my vocabulary from Hollywood movies.
- I learned a lot of my vocabulary from Hollywood movies.
- I learned some of my vocabulary from Hollywood movies.

Comment: By that argument wheat would be countable because it is made up of grains. I believe *much of* is quite correct and idiomatic in this context, though it is a little more formal than "a lot of"

Comment: Much of my mother's vocabulary was derived from her career in the navy.

Comment: I'm not sure that vocabulary really is as countable as you suggest. Are "hot", "hotter", "hottest", "hotly" different words in one's vocabulary? If not, how should we count it when somebody who previously knew only "hot" then learns "hotter"? If yes, suppose a person learns the word "weak" and also knows these patterns for changing adjectives into comparatives, superlatives and adverbs, so that they would be able to form "weaker", "weakest" and "weakly" when needed ─ but the person hasn't yet seen or formed those yet ─ how should we count them?

Comment: I would say that “vocabulary” is usually used either as a singular (“I have *a big* vocabulary”) or noncount (“OK, class, let’s learn some vocabulary”). The only way I can imagine it as count is when discussing the “word-hoards” specific to several people, groups, etc: “They have differing vocabularies.”

Comment: It's important to distinguish between grammatical properties and real-word properties. Vocabulary *consists* of words, and "word" is a count noun, but the *word* vocabulary is singular. Words that refer to a set can take "much" to describe their contents: "Much of my inventory", "Much of my staff", etc.